# Metrics Explorer - Disk Bytes Used unavailable

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a custom dashboard for my Compute Engine instances.  One of the metrics that I want to report on is the amount of free disk space available on each VM.  I noticed that "disk bytes used" is one of the available metrics but it is not actually available to me to select unless I disable the "Only Show Active" metrics.

I have the "OS Agent" (recently released) installed and running on the VMs.

I can't seem to find any documentation referencing this particular metric and how to get it working.

Has anyone tried this and figured out the magic solution?

Comment: You didn't mention which OS you are running in your Compute Engine.  Looking here:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-disk

I see that the metric may be "Linux Only".

Comment: Sorry, it is Linux that I am using as the OS.  That's what is confusing because it shows as an unavailable metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did in order to get the metrics working in a replicated environment:

1.-I created 2 GCE instances (Debian and RedHat).
[image]

2. Navigate to the Monitoring section, and select Dashboards.
   [image]

3.- Select the VM Instances Dashboard from the Dashboard List.
[image]

4.- From the Instances section, I selected both instances and clicked on Install Agents; it will open the Cloud Shell VM and auto populate the command to install the Ops Agent.
[image]
5.- You might need to wait up to 10 minutes to get the agents connected to the Monitoring Dashboard.

6.- Once you see the Ops Agent running on the instances, select the Infrastructure Summary Dashboard.
[image]
7.- Scroll down the Dashboard, and you will see the Top Disk Used (Agent) section populated.
[image]

If you prefer, you can also create a custom Dashboard.

1. On the Left Panel, navigate to the Metrics Explorer section.
   [image]
2. In the Resource type, select VM Instance (gce_instance), and, at the bottom, unselect the “Only show active” checkbox.
   [image]
3. In the Metric dropdown, menu select Disk Usage, and also unselect the “Only show active” checkbox.
   [image]
   4.- You need to wait at least 1 minute to see the chart populated.
   [image]

Here is the full list of metrics accepted for [gce_compute](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response.  I now see how to do.  I am experiencing an issue right now, with my VMs, where the Monitoring service does not believe I have installed the agent so it is not giving me the option to report on disk space used.  I have a ticket open with Google on that.